# Put all backups into one backup folder

Tags: backup

How can I set up Emacs so that all backups are placed into one backup folder? e.g. `/MyEmacsBackups`

Comment: Be aware that this could have the unintended side effect of leaving sensitive information lingering around on your machine, even after the originals are moved/deleted.  It would be advisable to purge this backup folder occasionally.  These backup files may also have different permissions than the originals.

Comment: **Related:** 
[How do I control how Emacs makes backup files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/151945/183120)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Check out `backup-directory-alist`, which allows you to set backup locations by file regexp. To have everything go to one directory, try something like:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("." . "~/MyEmacsBackups")))
```

For the truly paranoid (like myself), there's also [backup-each-save](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/backup-each-save.el), which (as the name suggests) backs up your files each time they're saved in a convenient location. This gives an extra layer of protection over traditional version control, for instance for those cases when you accidentally clear your working directory without checking something in.

Comment: I have done this but `ls -a ~/MyEmacsBackups` keep returning 0 file , what might be the reason ?

Answer (score 21):

The following is a quick code from my `.emacs`. It does not only put backups into a specific directory, but also auto-saves, and does the same for Tramp files so those are not put onto the remote system.

```el
;; Put backup files neatly away
(let ((backup-dir "~/tmp/emacs/backups")
      (auto-saves-dir "~/tmp/emacs/auto-saves/"))
  (dolist (dir (list backup-dir auto-saves-dir))
    (when (not (file-directory-p dir))
      (make-directory dir t)))
  (setq backup-directory-alist `(("." . ,backup-dir))
        auto-save-file-name-transforms `((".*" ,auto-saves-dir t))
        auto-save-list-file-prefix (concat auto-saves-dir ".saves-")
        tramp-backup-directory-alist `((".*" . ,backup-dir))
        tramp-auto-save-directory auto-saves-dir))

(setq backup-by-copying t    ; Don't delink hardlinks
      delete-old-versions t  ; Clean up the backups
      version-control t      ; Use version numbers on backups,
      kept-new-versions 5    ; keep some new versions
      kept-old-versions 2)   ; and some old ones, too
```

Answer (score 4):

```
;; put all backup files into ~/MyEmacsBackups
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("." . "~/MyEmacsBackups")))
(setq backup-by-copying t)
```

Comment: What benefit does your answer have over shosti's?

Comment: @Gilles Not much, https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup-Copying.html

Comment: Also, file mounts in docker [doesn't work well](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15793#issuecomment-135411504) with `(not backup-by-copying)`. Actually I'm not really sure why one would want the default behavior.