# Automatic deletion of backup files

Tags: backup, deletion

When editing files, some `foo.bar~`  backups appear  (files ending with a *tilde* ~). How can I control their creations, and is it possible to ask for a recursive bulk deletion of all files from a specific directory and all it's sub directories?

Comment: There are really 2 questions here; "How can I control their creations" seems like a partial duplicate of http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33/put-all-backups-into-one-backup-folder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make all backup files to go a directory with

```
(setq backup-directory-alist `(("." . "~/.emacs.bak")))
```

and turn it off completely with

```
(setq make-backup-files nil)
```

although nobody will recommend that.

Making backups for only some projects is not easy: you'll have to flip that variable in various hooks.

Finally, asking for bulk deletion is exactly equivalent to:

```
find . -name '*~' -exec rm {} \;
```

so you might be better of doing that in the shell.

Comment: might use -delete instead of -exec, it's much faster because it doesn't spawn new process.

Answer (score 4):

`dired` makes it easy to delete all the backup files in a directory--from `dired`, just type `~` to mark backup files for deletion and `x` to execute the deletion.

Answer (score 3):

From https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup-Names.html#Backup-Names

> You can customize the variable backup-directory-alist to specify that
>   files matching certain patterns should be backed up in specific
>   directories. This variable applies to both single and numbered
>   backups. A typical use is to add an element ("." . dir) to make all
>   backups in the directory with absolute name dir; Emacs modifies the
>   backup file names to avoid clashes between files with the same names
>   originating in different directories. Alternatively, adding, ("." .
>   ".~") would make backups in the invisible subdirectory .~ of the
>   original file's directory. Emacs creates the directory, if necessary,
>   to make the backup.
>
> If you define the variable make-backup-file-name-function to a
>   suitable Lisp function, that overrides the usual way Emacs constructs
>   backup file names.

You can also set EMACS to keep numbered backups and only keep a given number of backups, although this may be worse than just a single backup for each file.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup-Deletion.html