# Prevent emacs from saving previous versions of text files

Tags: saving

I am editing a lot of text files in emacs and the automatic saving of previous versions is creating a massive amount of extraneous files. For example, if I edit a file called    numbers.txt    and save, then there will be a    number.txt    file as well as a   number.txt~    file. I do not need to keep previous versions. Is there something I can add to my .emacs to prevent the saving of previous file versions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic deletion of backup files](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/automatic-deletion-of-backup-files)

Answer (score 1):

From [`(info "(emacs) Backup")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup.html):

> For most files, the variable ‘make-backup-files’ determines whether
>   to make backup files.  On most operating systems, its default value is
>   ‘t’, so that Emacs does write backup files.

So turn it off with:

```
(setq make-backup-files nil)
```

in your init file.